# ASP.NET mobile web site open source

Tags: asp.net, mobile-website

Can any one tell me a open source mobile web site in asp.net? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend searching on a MS centric code repository site such as CodePlex.

For example, I found nonCommerce ([Repo](http://nopcommerce.codeplex.com/), [Demo](http://www.nopcommerce.com/demo.aspx)).

Answer (score 1):

Try Codeplex: http://aspnetmobilesamples.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

The site http://phn.me/ has a "Mobile site creator" which is open source; see [their source download page](http://phn.me/opensource.htm) for more information.